# Error header location with MariaDB

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I changed my hosting need by passing a mariadb (php5.6), before I had innodb (php5.6).

The code in the previous hosting worked perfectly, why in this host no?

Code:

```
<?php
$risultato = mysql_query("SELECT voto FROM serveryoutube", $connessione);
if($mybb->user['uid'] > 0)
{
if(mysql_query("
UPDATE serveryoutube SET voto = voto + 1 WHERE id = '$id' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM serveryoutube_vote WHERE uid = '$uid' AND DATE_FORMAT(lastvote,'%m%d%Y') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m%d%Y'));
")) {
    header("Location: ../home.php"); }
else {
    echo "Error: " . mysql_error(); }
    } 
else { echo 'Error'; }
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

The query work and set +1 voto but I see white page and not redirect to /home.php

Comment: I see `$connessione` and I see `$con`; which connection variable are you really using? Plus, you get a white screen; that means you have syntax errors. PHP's error reporting will tell you what's wrong. I think your query failed and is outputting an error and that alone will trigger output, in turn triggering a headers sent notice.

Comment: As I said above the query works perfectly is just a header location problem. In fact I tried with an echo redirect and it works is just a header location problem, how come?

Comment: I mentioned what to do in my comment.

Comment: It is not a solution unfortunately

Comment: Come back _after_ changing from `mysql_*` API to either `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.